# is SimpleDateFormat not working in android 5.1.1?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I need to format a date, i am using SimpleDateFormat, but when i try to use it in any Lollipop device it does not parse the string, it throws me a parse error at index 3, as if it was expecting a date on the Nov, Dec, Mar format but the four M is for full month string November, December, March.

Its working fine in marshmallow but not in Lollipop, have't tried anywhere else, anyone know how to fix this?

```
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy hh:mm");
        Date nextDate = format.parse(mOverlord.getNextIrrigation().replaceAll("(?<=\\d)(,|st|nd|rd|th)", ""));
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
```

this is the error i am getting:

```
Unparseable date: "November 19 2016 21:54" (at offset 3)
```

Comment: Replace hh:mm with HH:mm and try

Comment: Can u post what is the value u r trying to parse? I have tried _November 19 2016 21:54_ it looks fine.

Comment: Must be `HH:mm` as saida bove

Comment: @Raghavendra Tried the HH:mm before posting the question nothing changes, thanks for the suggestions tho, are you using a 5.1.1 Android device? i am only getting the error there. It also works in the emulator for some reason...

Comment: Replace hh:mm with **kk:mm** as the hours are in 24-hour format.

Comment: @MonishKamble that was not the problem, it was the Locale, defining the Locale seems to be necessary to format dates in android 5.1, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is locale set to an appropriate value? You can enforce US locale if that's an option for you, the following code works for me:

```
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy hh:mm", Locale.US);
        Date x = formatter.parse("November 19 2016 21:54");
```

Comment: its odd, but this was the problem, thank you very much, i did not imagine i would need to add that in android 5.1 for it to work, thanks!